# Phoenix/HBase throws NoSuchMethodError: sun.misc.Unsafe.putLong on Windows

Tags: java, hbase, apache-phoenix

Our product uses Phoenix JDBC driver to connect HBase and it works fine on Linux. I wanted to run it on Windows but the connection failed.

I tried to connect from IntelliJ Idea's Database and it failed on the same error. I used to have a connection in Idea to another HBase installation which was working fine there in July. But it fails with the same error too.

```
2020-11-18 11:36:54,835 [ 119005]   INFO - .DatabaseConnectionEstablisher - Connecting to: jdbc:phoenix:dev.internal:2181:/hbase-unsecure 
2020-11-18 11:36:57,362 [ 121532]   WARN - .DatabaseConnectionEstablisher - Connecting to: jdbc:phoenix:dev.internal:2181:/hbase-unsecure 
2020-11-18 11:36:57,364 [ 121534]   WARN - .DatabaseConnectionEstablisher - [08004][103] ERROR 103 (08004): Unable to establish connection. 
2020-11-18 11:36:57,368 [ 121538]   WARN - ic.GenericDatabaseErrorHandler - ERROR 103 (08004): Unable to establish connection. 

java.sql.SQLException: ERROR 103 (08004): Unable to establish connection.
at org.apache.phoenix.exception.SQLExceptionCode$Factory$1.newException(SQLExceptionCode.java:542)
at org.apache.phoenix.exception.SQLExceptionInfo.buildException(SQLExceptionInfo.java:150)
at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.openConnection(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:460)
at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.access$400(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:292)
at  at org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixContextExecutor.call(PhoenixContextExecutor.java:76)
at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.init(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:3077)
at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.getConnectionQueryServices(PhoenixDriver.java:255)
at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.createConnection(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:142)
at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.connect(PhoenixDriver.java:221)

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void sun.misc.Unsafe.putLong(java.lang.Object, int, long)'
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.UnsafeAccess.putLong(UnsafeAccess.java:248)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes$ConverterHolder$UnsafeConverter.putLong(Bytes.java:1489)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes.putLong(Bytes.java:788)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientIdGenerator.generateClientId(ClientIdGenerator.java:51)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.PerClientRandomNonceGenerator.<init>(PerClientRandomNonceGenerator.java:37)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:698)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:649)
```

Idea decompiled `sun.misc.Unsafe` and there is:

```
@Deprecated
public void putLong(Object o, int offset, long x) {
    putLong(o, (long)offset, x);
}
```

Environment:

```
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_252-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)
```

Classpath in Idea:

[image]

```
echo %HADOOP_HOME%
C:\dev\core\jdbc\winutils

echo %PATH%
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\dev\core\jdbc\winutils\bin;
```

JDBC folder:

```
16.11.2020  17:05    <DIR>          winutils
08.07.2020  12:43            20 764 hbase-annotations-1.1.0.jar
08.07.2020  12:43         1 239 829 hbase-client-1.1.0.jar
08.07.2020  12:43           523 263 hbase-common-1.1.0.jar
08.07.2020  12:23           489 884 log4j-1.2.17.jar
17.12.2019  07:12       109 750 805 phoenix-4.15.0-HBase-1.5-client.jar
08.07.2020  12:16         3 074 133 phoenix-core-4.4.0-HBase-1.1.jar
08.07.2020  12:35        55 186 484 phoenix-shaded-4.4.0-HBase-1.1-1.jar
08.07.2020  12:48           533 455 protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar
08.07.2020  12:21            25 962 slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar
08.07.2020  12:21             8 869 slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar
08.07.2020  12:50           792 964 zookeeper-3.4.6.jar
```

How to fix it?

Comment: What version of Phoenix are you using?  In your JDBC folder listing it looks like you have a mix of jars from different Phoenix versions (4.4 and 4.15).

Comment: There were several problems. I created a trivial JDBC application and it failed too. It failed on server with incompatible Phoenix driver. So I downgraded the client to 4.4 and it started to work. But not on my machine. Later I found that HBase is listening on loopback. Once we switched it to 0.0.0.1, it worked on windows too. But I still cannot make Idea work.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add `thin:url=http://` before the hostname (or IP) to fix that.

I was getting similar error in DBeaver Windows client and the problem was misconstructed jdbc URL. And i was using thin client jar got from installation directory of Phoenix.

Without the addition jdbc URL was missing this part.